# Seperate objects by loose parts automatically in python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

A have some objects that undergo several boolean. This leaves parts as unconnected. I know that I can:

1. Enter edit mode
2. Enter face select
3. Select a face
4. "Ctrl+L" for select linked all (done in picture below)
5. "p" separate by loose parts

I can see the corresponding python command and could just write it in a script. EXCEPT step 3) above. I can select a face, sure, but do I then have to loop over *all* faces and try to select linked? I suppose that I could count the number of selected faces and check it is equal to *all* faces, hence no unconnected part. But this seems very clumcy.

It there an elegant way to separate unconnected part into individual objects??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've search quite a while now. But just after posting this I stumpled on the answer **sigh**. If any one else is interested:

1. Enter edit mode
2. press "a" to select all vertices
3. press "p" to separate by loose parts

Comment: Yes that's the best solution. No Python scripting required. You can mark your question as answered.